# using webservices to make a phonegap application

Tags: cordova

I'm new to phone gap and trying to make my first web-service based app. the question is that how should I send request to a web-service and receive the answer?
and another question is that , can I user angular js for making the app or just j Query is allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to send requests to a web service: you can use any JavaScript framework or library you're comfortable with, and make the request like you would from the web.  You will need to pay attention to configuring the Content Security Policy meta tag in your HTML as Cordova 5 enforces that.  You may also (if your requests go to servers not secured with SSL) need to look into iOS 9's App Transport Security settings.  Both of these are well documented here on StackOverflow.

Can you use Angular? Absolutely - you can use any library or framework, just bundle it and any dependencies into the app so that all of that JS is local to the app and can be retrieved at startup without making a network request.  I've built Cordova apps with no JS framework, JQuery, Sencha Touch, Angular and they all work well.  If you want a UI framework take a look at Ionic or Onsen or even Bootstrap works well depending on your needs and skillset.